# How to remove the trailing slashes from a URL with nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, node.js

I'm trying to remove trailing slashes from urls. I searched a lot and tried some solutions but they didn't work form me.

I tried this one

`rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;`

but it leaves one slash at the end (example.com/ or example.com/post/) but I need example.com and example.com/post

Also I tried this solution

```
if ($request_uri ~ (.*?\/)(\/+)$ ) 
{
  return 301 $scheme://$host$1;
}
```

and it's one of the best but it also leaves one slash at the end.

And also I was getting an error in the console after all tries like this:

```
GET http://example.com/post 404 (Not Found)
```

I'm new to nginx and doesn't know a lot, how can I achieve redirects from urls with trailing slashes?

Comment: How many backslashes are being requested. Have you got urls like example.com/// or something silly like that. The rewrite you have used should work, but I guess Nginx assumes only one backslash. You might need to repeat it for // and /// etc.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? In case of  "example.com/", that slash isn't "trailing", it's the first character of every url. Remove it, your browserr will add it again.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille agree with that, but how can I remove slash in this case 'example.com/post/'? Because when I'm trying url like this 'example.com/post////' it leaves one slash at the end - 'example.com/post/', I want remove that slash too.

Comment: @AdmiralNoisyBottom, two and more slashes are being requested ( example.com//////), I'll try to repeat that rewrite, but how exactly should I do that just paste few of them or make some changes?

Answer (score 0):

No ifs (or buts) are needed, a rewrite will do:

```
rewrite /((?U).*)(/+)$ /$1 redirect;
```

Without the "ungreedy" - (?U) - $1 would pick up all but one /.

Comment: this results in "too many redirects" for me @Gerard

Comment: Not from this rewrite, @AATHITHRAJENDRAN.  Better open a new question with your full nginx configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This one worker for me:

```
location ~ (.*)/$ {
  if ($query_string) {
    return 301 $scheme://$host$1?$query_string;
  }
  return 301 $scheme://$host$1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution has also been tested and works well.

It should have a better performance because there is no rewriting according to the best practice above.

```
location ~ (.*?\/)(\/+)$ {
  return 301 $scheme://$host$request_uri;
}
```